# In Collection.find, how to format .limit, .sort, fieldlist, and variable column names

Tags: meteor

In non Meteor Server-Side calls to mongodb it is possible make the following chained-option call to the database

```
    collection.find( { myField: { $gte: myOffset } ).limit( myLimit ).sort( { mySortField : 1 } );
```

where myField, myOffset, myLimit and mySortField may be resolved from elsewhere at run-time.

This pattern is very useful to create such a run-time generated generic query.

Meteor seems to insist on the non-chained options pattern of

```
    collection.find( { { myField: { $gte: myOffset } }, { limit: myLimit, sort: { mySortField : 1 }} );
```

and I am having problems 'building up' a working Find Query as required above from js objects as described 
in previous questions 17362401 and 10959729

Would anyone like to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to show usage of variable:

I do it this way.  You send two hashes, where the first is the where clause, and all else are peer level keys.

```
var locations;
var myfield = 'gps';

search = {      
  sureties: {
    $in: sureties
  }
}

search[myfield] = {
    $near: this.gps,
    $maxDistance: kilometers 
  };

locations = Agents.find(search, {
  fields: {
    name: 1,
    phone: 1
  },
  limit: limit,
  sort: { field1 : 1 }
}).fetch();
```

Comment: From my question you can read that myField is also a run-time variable for example gps in your example. Then, it becomes more difficult to use this pattern.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect variable field name.

Answer (score 0):

The chained pattern is not possible in Meteor, neither server side nor on the client. But the params pattern is as universal, you should be able to create any query you need with those params.